# Trigger Github Actions (use Github API) on an organization's account that I have access to

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

My company has a Github account with numerous repositories. I, as a lowly web engineer, want to use my PAT (personal access token) to trigger Github Actions on one of my company's repos. The company doesn't want to give me any special **organization admin** access or anything like that. This seems like it should be possible but we haven't found a way to do this.

I'm trying to trigger the Github Action via API.

Comment: What are the triggers for the workflow?  Can you change the triggers - in other words, can you edit the workflow?  If so, you can trigger based on a repository dispatch event. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event

Comment: yes, i am the owner of the company's repo, just not the company's account. I am building the workflow from scratch to get this working.